# if a text_field_tag form helper in rails is disabled, does it not submit?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-helpers

I have a text_field_tag in my form, i really want it just for display (all my jquery updates this text field), using a date picker.  Though I don't want the user to type in here, so I said the `:disabled => true` and sure enough it is disabled, values change here but in my ajax remote call they do not save, only if that text_field_tag is enabled does it save.  Is there any work around this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `:readonly => true` instead.

An important difference between `readonly` and `disabled` is that `disabled` does not include the  field when the form is submitted while `readonly` does.

Comment: I don't know how i missed that.  Thanks!